# Remove button border windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, border

Is there a way to remove the white border of the button.I added an image to the button and I got this border. I tried with `button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;` but it doesn't work.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 14):

You need to set the button to use the flat appearance.

```
button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
```